# How to configure Nginx webserver to use AWS RDS SSL while maintaining https between Nginx webserver and visitor browser

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

I have an Nginx web-server running on EC2 and an amazon RDS mysql instance with encryption enabled at instance creation time. This is using an encryption key I create using IAM.

**Question 1:** What's the purpose of this encryption key? It is just to encrypt data at rest?

Then I'm trying to use SSL provided by RDS (rds-ca-2015-root.pem) to encrypt data in motion between Nginx web-server and RDS mysql instance.

**Question 2:** Do I have to copy .pem file to Nginx server and do some configuration? Please list the steps if possible.

After, I want Nginx web-server to communicate with visitors browser over HTTPS when submitting login info and other sensitive information.

**Question 3:** How can I do this? Do I need another SSL certificate from a CA and how do I configure this in Nginx server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: What's the purpose of this encryption key?

It looks like it's for SSL communication to your MySQL instance. To talk to securely talk to your instance, you must [configure your MySQL client with that .pem file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport).

> It is just to encrypt data at rest?

No, for that, you just check a checkbox at RDS database instance creation time. There is nothing else to do.

> to encrypt data in motion between Nginx web-server and RDS mysql instance.

Nginx doesn't talk to MySQL. (Well, maybe you have some strange nginx module?) Whatever is talking to MySQL must be configured for SSL mode (and for security, must be given the public key .pem file to verify it's talking to the right server.)

> Question 2: Do I have to copy .pem file to Nginx server and do some configuration? Please list the steps if possible.

Yes. Since Nginx doesn't talk to MySQL directly, you need to figure out what is talking to MySQL. (Is it some nginx module? Look at that module doc for directives. Otherwise, nginx is probably fronting for some other app such as PHP-FPM, etc. That app must be configured for SSL to MySQL.)

> Question 3: Do I need another SSL certificate from a CA and how do I configure this in Nginx server?

Yes, there is a complex dance you need to do to get SSL working. There are many pages on how to do that. You'll need to ask a specific question if you want help with that.